# Could not link assemblies. Reason Object reference not set to an instance of an object - MTOUCH

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

i'm working with xamarin.forms but when I go to test my app on a physical iOS device I get the error: Could not link assemblies. Reason Object reference not set to an instance of an object in the file MTOUCH. How can I fix this error? I've searched all over for answers but nothing works, for example I have tried turning off the linker but that just spits out new problems, so please don't mark this as a duplicate question because none of the others answers have worked and I really need help, thanks. Here is my MSBuild log:

```
Target ResolveAssemblyReferences:
No way to resolve conflict between "System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
No way to resolve conflict between "System.Diagnostics.Debug, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Diagnostics.Debug, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Diagnostics.Debug, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
No way to resolve conflict between "System.Threading.Tasks, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Threading.Tasks, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Threading.Tasks, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
No way to resolve conflict between "System.Linq.Expressions, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Linq.Expressions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Linq.Expressions, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
No way to resolve conflict between "System.Collections, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Collections, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Collections, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
No way to resolve conflict between "System.Reflection, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Reflection, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Reflection, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
No way to resolve conflict between "System.Threading, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Threading, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Threading, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
No way to resolve conflict between "System.ObjectModel, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.ObjectModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.ObjectModel, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
No way to resolve conflict between "System.Globalization, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Globalization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Globalization, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
No way to resolve conflict between "System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
No way to resolve conflict between "System.IO, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.IO, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.IO, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
No way to resolve conflict between "System.Dynamic.Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Dynamic.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Dynamic.Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
No way to resolve conflict between "System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
No way to resolve conflict between "System.Text.RegularExpressions, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Text.RegularExpressions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Text.RegularExpressions, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
No way to resolve conflict between "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" and "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed". Choosing "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" arbitrarily.
No way to resolve conflict between "System.Net.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Net.Primitives, Version=3.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Net.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
No way to resolve conflict between "System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
No way to resolve conflict between "System.Text.Encoding, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Text.Encoding, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Text.Encoding, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
No way to resolve conflict between "System.Xml.XDocument, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Xml.XDocument, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Xml.XDocument, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
No way to resolve conflict between "System.Text.Encoding.Extensions, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Text.Encoding.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Text.Encoding.Extensions, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
```

Comment: Turn on MSBuild Diagnostic level logging and review the output for more details concerning the issue, I would ***assume*** you will find a bad assembly reference

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks for the quick response, where would I find the MSBuild setting, I am running Visual Studio Community for Mac.

Comment: Under `Preferences` / `Project` / `Build`

Comment: @SushiHangover ok I don't see that specific setting however I see build with msbuild instead of build which I would figure is the same thing, if so where do I find this output

Comment: It is contained in the `Error` pad (right-hand side)

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks, just updated the answer to include the log

Comment: Review the log to see where the first error happens (not the summary) and see if there are any more details

Comment: @SushiHangover updated, it seems to be several conflicts, how should I fix this?

Comment: @AppleGeek, were you able to find any solutions here? I'm running into a similar error, and need to be able to build ios. My emulator builds fine, but I can't push it to a device due to this error.

Comment: @Nieminen no I haven't sorry

Comment: @AppleGeek Thanks for your response, I ended up finding my issue. It turns out I had a `Mono.Android` reference in my shared project that apple couldn't resolve. Removing that (and the small amount of code that used it) fixed my apple device build issue.

Comment: @Nieminen sounds like a good fix where exactly did you find it and what code would I be deleting?

Comment: @AppleGeek In my case is was my own code that I added, so it'll be individual to your project. I was doing custom android logic in my shared project, that required a reference to Mono.Android (which causes ios to fail apparently). **IF** you have the same problem, just remove the `Mono.Android` reference in your shared project, and try to run it, the compiler will show you all the places (if any) that need that reference for you to remove/work around.

Comment: @AppleGeek The way I found that Mono.Android was my issue, was I started systematically removing references in my shared project, fixing any errors they caused when missing, and trying to run in ios after each reference had been taken care of. Another option would be to create a new project, and slowly move your existing code over to it (building and running along the way). That way once it fails, you'll have an idea which code/dependencies are to blame.